# GPG on Linux within weblogic (Java command)

Tags: linux, weblogic, gnupg

I need help please. I have a java program that breaks out to the command line to run a gpg decryption. It works perfectly standalone on my Windows pc. Then I run it from within a container (Weblogic) and still it works perfectly on my Windows PC. When I moved it to our Linux server...gpg error. It says "gpg cannot open file..." and then my filename (with the wildcard). I print out the command just before it is executed. If I copy this command exactly, I can run it on linux. I even for completeness sake printed out the exact location that the app is running from and ran the decryption command from there - also works. Please - any ideas would be really welcome. Why doesn't it work from within the container?

```
String command = "gpg --batch --allow-multiple-messages --decrypt-files --passphrase " + passPhrase + " " + filePathName + "/" + fileName + ".pgp";
  logInfo(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Executing command : [" + command + "]");
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

This is what the command printed out looks like:

gpg --batch --allow-multiple-messages --decrypt-files --passphrase mypassphrase /usr/local/applications/mybatch/dataImportFiles/*_REW_BAL.txt.pgp

Comment: Why does it have a wilcard?

Comment: It is part of a batch import. The files come in every day with a unique number and datestamp. Ony the last part of the files are the same. I tested the line with the wildcard as I wondered if this was the error, but the wildcard works on the command line.

Comment: If you test it with a real filename does it work?

Comment: I tested it now without the wildcard. It works indeed. This is very strange. The wildcard works on the command line. Does it have something to do with how the wildcard character is rendered through the container? I need this wildcard :(

Comment: Yeah, maybe try escaping it.